# React JS: Browser console displays, "Uncaught TypeError: type.apply is not a function" and page comes out blank

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

I am new to React js so I was following a tutorial online that would take me through the basics and I got stuck many times. My problems ranged from the watch task not detecting changes to infinite building which i found solutions for online. But this particular  problem has been very hard to solve and i decided for the first time to post my problem in a forum.

The jsx file is in a different file which is compiled using react tools i downloaded through NPM. when i open the browser, it says

```
Uncaught TypeError: type.apply is not a function
```

And the page remains blank. When i check the mount-point div in the developer tools, it contains nothing

Here is the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Timer</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="js/react.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
    <div id="mount-point"></div>
    <script src="js/react-code.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my jsx file.

```
var counter = React.createClass({
incrementCount: function(){
    this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + 1
    })
},
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        count: 0
    }
},
render: function(){
    return (
        <div class="my-component">
            <h1>Count: {this.state.count} </h1>
            <button type="button" onClick={this.incrementCount}>Increment </button>
        </div> 
    );
}
});

React.renderComponent(<counter/>, document.getElementById('mount-point'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're using JSX, React components need to be referenced by a variable with an initial upper case letter.

See [HTML Tags vs. React Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components)

> React's JSX uses the upper vs. lower case convention to distinguish between local component classes and HTML tags.

It looks like the tutorial you're using is for an old version of React, as `React.renderComponent()` was replaced with `React.render()` a couple of versions ago. Here's a working snippet using the latest version:

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://fb.me/react-0.13.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://fb.me/JSXTransformer-0.13.2.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
<script type="text/jsx;harmony=true">void function() { "use strict";

var Counter = React.createClass({
  incrementCount() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    })
  },
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  render() {
    return <div className="my-component">
      <h1>Count: {this.state.count}</h1>
      <button type="button" onClick={this.incrementCount}>Increment </button>
    </div> 
  }
})

React.render(<Counter/>, document.getElementById('app'))

}()</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I tried your code, downloaded the particular version you used and it worked like magic. thanks again